# Algorithm for ordering a set

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of 50 items and many conditions that specificy which element should come before other.

How to I create a ordered list?

Will like it in C# though can translate it from other languages.

Comment: I imagine you'll want to use a sorting algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). If you want to know something more specific, you need to provide more details.

Comment: sorting needs comparison between all items. I do not have it for all elements with each other

Comment: noidea why vote negative when answer has +ve vote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: Good suggestion, particularly if the "conditions" the OP mentions constitute a partial ordering.

Comment: @Thomas this is exactly the way I understood the OP's question, it's badly formulated though, I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Translate the "many conditions" into a comparison function, and then use that in conjunction with a comparison-based sort (in the general case).

The best comparison-based sorting algorithms are O(nlogn) in the best case. Merge sort is one such algorithm and is pretty easy to implement... there are many others.

If your conditions constitute a partial ordering (rather than a total ordering), Topological sort might be most appropriate.

Comment: sorting needs comparison between all items. I do not have it for all elements with each other.

Comment: But guaranteeing that the comparison function is transitive would be nontrivial. i.e. if you have the conditions `A<B` and `B<C` you'd need to guarantee that the comparison function knows that `A<C`.

Comment: Good point. Then again, if a > b > c > a, the problem probably isn't one of sorting but of arranging e.g. guests at a dinner table.

Comment: transitivity check is part of topological sort, it all relates to graph theory, where a relation is represented as a directed edge, cycle checking is very easy and can be done in linear by the number of relations time.

Comment: @Thomas: The problem is one of topological sorting, not of "normal" sorting where you can compare any two values.

Comment: @interjay: Yes, which is why I mention topological sort. In fairness, the OP didn't really give enough information initially to tell what was meant.

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of sorting algorithms you can look into.  The two that come to mind off the top of my head are the bubble sort and the quick sort.

Comment: Yep, downvote with any comments.  Gj, guys.

Comment: you rush to answer while not understanding the question, that's the reason.

Comment: And yet your answer was not different than mine, other than the suggested sort algorithm.  OP's question was too vague to form a concrete answer anyway.

Comment: @MGZero: actually, the answer unkulunkulu gave is better since it addresses the issue of a partial order. Though he didn't elaborate at all, he did provide a useful link, which is why I voted his answer up. Thomas's answer is more thorough and took more time, so I voted that up as well. Your answer is more a restatement of the question, with two suggestions that aren't too relevant and have no elaboration. That's why I did not vote your answer up. But that's just me.

Comment: Oh, please don't take this the wrong way, I don't mind the downvote, I just like to know WHY I'm downvoted :) Helps me understand problems as well. +1 for actually posting a useful reason.